# How do i create an OpenID login form

Tags: php, authentication, openid

i am wanting to create an open id login, i am wondering if i use one of the classes from [Creating an OpenID Login widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162513/creating-an-openid-login-widget), like [openid selector library](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) or [openid real selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-realselector/). btw, is realselector newer/better, since its a rewrite of openid selector library

is there a getting started tutorial? i see that in both i can easily login using open id. but how will my application handle the login? like i guess my app needs to handle the postback from google or something? eg. in stackoverflow, i will go and create my profile? how will i check also that the user has logged in and which user. eg. in PHP, i may store a session variable `$_SESSION["userid"]` and check for it.

in [Staying logged in between pages](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/wiki/StayingLoggedInBetweenPages) it tells me to check for cookie, but what cookie isit? what if i want to check in PHP/ASP.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend made a rather good article about this subject on their site. 
http://devzone.zend.com/article/3581

There they explain how it works and shows a lot of example code. I have not been working with
the classes you are mentioning, but the zend-article might give you some clues of how to solve some of your questions :)

Comment: ok, i am reading it up. but i guess the ability of [openid selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) to login using [only javascript](http://openid-selector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demoOpenIDClient.html) opens new posibilities -> i think like independence from server model. so i would like to know how can i work with that. the google code site for both solutions don't seem to have a good getting started tutorial or documentation

Comment: in the article link you provided, u have `session_start(); // needed for YADIS` i guess its needed for me/PHP to know if the user has logged in across pages? not only for YADIS whatever it is? and i guess `$store = new Auth_OpenID_FileStore('./oid_store');` is *always* needed, by `Auth_OpenID_Consumer`? is there a documentation for these files? or how did u get started with understanding these in the 1st place?

Comment: in `$url = $auth->redirectURL('http://consumer.example.com/' ... // redirect to OpenID provider for authentication`, how come its not redirect to google for example but your site to login?

Comment: i have tried to do `$auth = $consumer->begin("http://openid-provider.appspot.com/")` and 1 with `https` but it always fails. am i doing the right thing?

Comment: Funny - single reference to single article on huge web... OpenID that is.

Comment: update the link i used is [http://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id](https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id) not the appspot 1, either way, i think i need the **identifier** not the **provider** how do i get the identifier?

Comment: The link is dead. Can you find another one?