# PHP: Options to generate an unique user key

Tags: php, hash, key

After a few days researching on hashing, generating random numbers or unique keys, I am a bit confusing now.

I have one last thing that I want to get it right which is the user key. I want to store an unique key for each member/ user who registers at my website. So this key must be unique and not duplicate. I am thinking to use the user email and hash it with timedate or something...

Then I wonder which is the best way to create such a key -

**Can I use [hash_hmac()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) to do this for me?**

I have a couple of things don't understand about [hash_hmac()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) though - as in this example from the php.net `hash_hmac('ripemd160', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', 'secret');`

So what is 'secret' - can I put anything different instead, like a timedate?
I assume that I can replace 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' with the email address?

**or maybe I can use [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) to do this?**

the only thing is that it produces `.`, `$`, and `/` which I need to remove them otherwise I will get errors when I request the key from the URL.

so I might do this -

```
$hash = $phpass -> HashPassword('me@example.com'.$timedate)
$key = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $hash);
```

Please let me know if you have any better suggestions.

Comment: is a simple md5() function insufficient for your purposes? or does the string need to be decodable as well? md5(), when using i.e. a user ID (which should be unique by itself it you're using a DB) and let's say e-mail address will provide a string with the fixed length of 32 characters that you can use and is almost impossible to decode by a 3rd party

Comment: What do you need this unique user key for?

Comment: @Gumbo♦: I use it for identification when the user verifies their email address, etc. for instance I will send an email when one registers and ask him/her to click on a verification link like - http://xx.com/verify/(key) - does it make sense?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I have one last thing that I want to
>   get it right which is the user key. I
>   want to store an unique key for each
>   member/ user who registers at my
>   website. So this key must be unique
>   and not duplicate. I am thinking to
>   use the user email and hash it with
>   timedate or something

- I would just let your database handle this for you using [autoincrement](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)
- You could also use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) for this: `md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));`

**index.php:**

```
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    echo md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)) . "\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
php index.php 
ba0d9aad1ff0ceadf4b25f101099b91e
b5a6db5e174b426061d3d3835a6fcaea
54be6d3a03e0590917ed20b097442e3a
6e208a61eae8cfd102d4a41decf0f64e
2cafac5402815af87e8299e5e67016bd
95e839097a566471c70fe357e5a101d2
c6908532bda6f926debdda754b02f931
aac7adf999dd4dd009f208b176ea90d0
1ed7779229e57b05adc088b375582cfb
e016a684564d5cdb89201ebab1038609
```

They are all unique and you can just use them. You should NOT have to do anything else?

Comment: @Alfred: thanks. can I add the email address into md5 to hash with it like - md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE).$email);?

Comment: You could, but why do you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: @Alfred: just in case md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); itself is not enough to create the unique key! so adding the email would make it 100% unique! lol or is it not necessary?

Comment: 'If set to TRUE, uniqid() will add additional entropy (using the combined linear congruential generator) at the end of the return value, which should make the results more unique.'  We can also activate the more_entropy parameter, which is required on some systems, like Cygwin. This makes uniqid() produce a value like: 4b340550242239.64159797' it seems that I can rest assure on uniqid() but I must get rid of the dot...

Comment: **autoincrement**, seriously. Why use anything else? has emails and people can't change their emails, or can't share emails (some married couples actually do this)

Comment: @andrew I am also suggesting that, but he wants to use something else ?

Comment: @andrew: autoincrement - do you mean the auto-increment on the ID column?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: no problem. You got a satisfying solution now? I am still wondering why you just don't use autoincrement. That is what is for!

Comment: @Alfred: the reason I can't use autoincrement is that I think I can't send the key like this to the user to ask them to verify their email i think - xx.com/verify/1  - the number 1 might be the first id auto-increment when the user registers at my site - does it make sense?

Comment: also I have two tables for store user data - one is temporary which store the users who have not verified their emails yet (or they might be spams) while another is permanant/ confirmed which stores the users who have verified their emails. the user in the temp table will be deleted immediately when this user verified the email and his/her data will be moved to the permanent table. so I imagine that autoincrement might get confusing when there are two tables like these two.

Comment: so I want to use one unique key for these two tables. and this unique will be generated and store in the temp table when the user registers at my site. this unique then will be moved to the permanent table when the user verifies his/ her email.

Comment: I know understand your problem a little better, but could I make another observation. You should not write a login-system yourself because it is very hard to do it write(no security vulnerabilities). You should use something like [lightopenid](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid) instead. Very easy library to implement openid on your site. Also I even if you don't use openid(I really advice you would!), I don't think you should have two tables, but only 1 with a `verified` field.

Comment: @Alfred: thanks for introducing the lightopenid to me - I will have a look see. thank you for your help :-)

Comment: @lauthiamkok no problem. You should use openid. It is safer. Don't get into the same trouble as [lifehacker did](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/12/the-dirty-truth-about-web-passwords.html) => interesting read in my opinion.

Comment: @Alfred: I am now googling about lightopenid to see how I can integrate it with my site! :-)

Comment: I would use google authentication. The [example](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/master/example-google.php) just works. You only need to add the $openid->identity  to your $_SESSION. If you want to make it persistent you should store an unique cookie(use [http-only cookie](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)) and make cookie unique by issuing `md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE))`

Comment: @Alfred: thanks for tips again. one question as I still can't get my head around this openid yet - does the user needs to have an email account at google, facebook, twitter or something? or the user must to have their account at google? what happen if the user doesn't have an account with at google? as I know there are people really hate facebook and never ever touch it.

Comment: Lol that are stupid people if you ask me :). OpenID can be used with any OpenID provider. I advise you to watch this [funny video to learn how OpenID works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcmY8Pk-qEk). But then you should use some [nice widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162513/creating-an-openid-login-widget/1162551#1162551). You see that stackoverflow also uses openid ;)!

Comment: I have just created a library you can use. I am going to upload it to github for you real soon ;).

Comment: @ Alfred: thank you so much - i am going to like this openid very much! thanks!! :-)

Comment: yes. it works beautifully! thank you. http://nano-visions.net/dump/ how can I add facebook and twitter as OpenID providers? when the page returns to my test site - how can I grab, like, username, their profile pictures, ect? there must be some guides elsewhere - I'll look it up! :-)

Comment: grabbing username => http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/wiki/GettingMoreInformation. P.S: facebook does not use openid, but oauth2.0. The wrapped it around(created) facebook connect library.

Comment: updated my library(github link) to support extra information. I will add profile picture via gravatar when I get back. Need to go first!

Comment: I have tested the updated version - now I know how to get some more info from the provider. so if I want to print the email of the user into my html, can I do this <p>echo $openid->getAttributes('namePerson/friendly');</p> - it doesn't work obviously!

Comment: $openid->getAttributes is an associative array ;). Just retrieve it from the array. I will update the code to also display your profile picture from gravatar. One second ;)

Comment: awww - $attributes['contact/email'] - why didn't I think of that! arggg... get the newest version and tested it. work perfectly! a million thanks Alfred!

Comment: XMPP is a open-source chat implementation. oops I posted wrong JID => you should be using XMPP: alfredwesterveld@jabber.org. First install pidgin and next configure pidgin to use your jabber.org jid => this video should help you out => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LCiLeRxo6E

Comment: Hehe no problem :). That you did not already have pidgin installed in the first place ;)

Comment: no I didn't - never heard about it before. it sounds fun! thank you :-)

Comment: np. You got XMPP running yet :P? Otherwise we could just quickly chat using http://dada.speeqe.com/

Answer (score 2):

I recommend "stealing" the [drupal_random_bytes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_random_bytes/7) function.

Answer (score 0):

About hash_hmac():
I believe the "secret" is just some string that is only known by you and the code. It is used to help randomize the algorithm and make it unique depending on which "secret" key you used. Just pick any phrase that you know, and put it there.
Note: this has to be the same value every time you hash if you expect the same value in return. So make it something constant, not variable, lest your hash return a different value *every* time you use it.

But yes, replace the "quick brown fox" with whatever you want to hash, and it should work.

Also an option: use the primary key of the user [usually a simple integer] from the database to reference them.